# Machine Learning Algorithm Android Spell Check and Auto Correct

Tags: android, machine-learning, autocorrect, spell-checking

I am curious to know if Android uses any machine learning algorithm for the spell check and the auto correct functionality while typing text? If yes, then is there a way to know which algorithm they use?

Many Thanks 
Rajat

Answer (score 4):

Can not prevent myself from dropping [it](http://xkcd.com/1068/) here.

The each keyboard uses it's own algorithms. I can assume that those algorithms are based on word frequency, Bayes decisions and edit distances(for spell check).

The learning part, in my opinion - is writing down the words that user writes more often and to offer them as autocorrect for similar words.

Comment: +1 for xkcd. I would also like to think that a significant amount of work goes in composing the dictionary as well.

Comment: There are dictionaries that are available online and even for free. I recommend you NLP course from coursera.org, this gives you great tools to work on language processing.